# List contains is not working

Tags: android, list, contains

I'm try to find out which Polyline a user has pushed on a Google Map. But my code below is not returning what I expect:

```
String k999 = "lat/lng";

List Klick = polyline.getPoints();

System.out.println("The list contains one " + Klick.contains(k999));
System.out.println("The list contains two " + Klick.contains("52.3524921"));
System.out.println("The list contains three " + "[lat/lng:".contains("[lat/lng:"));
System.out.println("Str-Str: " + Klick.contains(Klick));
System.out.println("equals: " + Klick.equals(Klick));
System.out.println("List: " + Klick);
```

The Output:

```
The list contains one false
The list contains two false
The list contains three true
Str-Str: false
equals: true
List: [lat/lng: (52.3524987,7.709607499999999), lat/lng: (52.3524921,7.7098328).........
```

Why doesn't my `contains` code work?

Comment: What type of object is `polyline`?

Comment: btw, `"[lat/lng:".contains("[lat/lng:)"` will always return true. You are checking if a string contains itself, not your list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Klick List object is actually a list of LatLng objects:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html#getPoints()

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html#toString()

When you System.out.println(Klick), you are actually calling the toString() method on each of those LatLng objects. If you look at the LatLng class, you can see that the toString method looks like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return "lat/lng: (" + this.latitude + "," + this.longitude + ")";
}
```

When you do a .contains() operation on a List, each object has its .equals() method called on it. For LatLng's, that method is:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(this == o) {
        return true;
    } else if(!(o instanceof LatLng)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        LatLng var2 = (LatLng)o;
        return Double.doubleToLongBits(this.latitude) == Double.doubleToLongBits(var2.latitude) && Double.doubleToLongBits(this.longitude) == Double.doubleToLongBits(var2.longitude);
    }
}
```

So, if you're trying to figure out what LatLng's your polyline has, you can do something like:

```
for(int i = 0, size = Klist.size(); i < size; i++) {
    LatLng currentLatLng = (LatLng)Klist.get(i);
    // do something with your LatLng
    double latitude = currentLatLng.latitude;
    double longitude = currentLatLng.longitude;
    System.out.printf("Latitude is %f. Longitude is %f", latitude, longitude);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after hours of coding it runs ;-)
A big thank to you !

```
List Klick = polyline.getPoints();

for(int i = 0, size = Klick.size(); i < size; i++) {
    LatLng currentLatLng = (LatLng) Klick.get(i);
    String KL = Klick.toString();

    // do something with your LatLng
    double latitude1 = currentLatLng.latitude;
    double longitude1 = currentLatLng.longitude;
    System.out.printf("\nLatitude: "+KL);
    System.out.printf("\ncontains: "+KL.contains("52.3524987"));
```

The Output:

```
Latitude: [lat/lng: (52.3524987,7.709607499999999), lat/lng: (52.3524921,7.7098328), lat/lng: (52.3534915,7.710031300000001).......
contains: true
```